# Data processing for time series data-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series

Given the below sample data,

> ```
> t- timeseries datetime sample,
> lat-latitude,
> long-longitude
> ```

```
t   lat long
0   27  28
5   27  28
10  27  28
15  29  49
20  29  49
25  27  28
30  27  28
```

I want to get the output similar to this, I want to process the time series data in such a way that grouping the pair of lat long I am able to get the distinct time series interval for the pair.
I am doing the processing in spark

```
Lat-long    interval
(27,28) (0,10)
(29,49) (15,20)
(27,28) (25,30)
```

Comment: reason for downvotes?

Comment: how big is your data? your requirement needs data to be collected and be looped without using distributed parallel processing

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am processing the day wise data which is stored in cassandara ,size of 5-6k rows of records/second , through distributed parallel processing using dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

**I wouldn't have suggested you this solution if your data were huge** but since you commented

> > I am processing the day wise data which is stored in cassandara ,size of 5-6k rows of records/second

following solution proposal should be fine

Looking at your given *dataframe*, *schema* should be as

```
root
 |-- t: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- lat: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- long: integer (nullable = false)
```

And **your expected output suggests that you would need an additional column for grouping the dataframe which would require you to collect the data on one executor**

```
val collectedRDD = df.collect()

var varianceCount, lattitude, longitude = 0
val groupedData = new ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]()
for(rdd <- collectedRDD) {
  val t = rdd.getAs[Int]("t")
  val lat = rdd.getAs[Int]("lat")
  val long = rdd.getAs[Int]("long")
  if (lat != lattitude || long != longitude) {
    varianceCount = varianceCount + 1
    lattitude = lat
    longitude = long
    groupedData.append((t, lat, long, varianceCount))
  }
  else {
    groupedData.append((t, lat, long, varianceCount))
  }
}
```

Then you *convert the ArrayBuffer to dataframe* and use `groupBy` and `aggregation` as

```
val finalDF = groupedData
  .toDF("t", "lat", "long", "grouped")
      .groupBy(struct("lat", "long").as("lat-long"), col("grouped"))
      .agg(struct(min("t"), max("t")).as("interval"))
    .drop("grouped")
```

`finalDF` should be

```
+--------+--------+
|lat-long|interval|
+--------+--------+
|[29,49] |[15,20] |
|[27,28] |[0,10]  |
|[27,28] |[25,30] |
+--------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer,cleared many things.How to go about if the data is huge? Because as process goes further data would definitely become huge.

Comment: and also how to deal with the problems of data distribution during parallel processing since this is a time series data and ordering and some part of "interval" would be affected if data is distributed,how to map that difference .I am newbie in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that case you will have to change the requirement . as your requirement suggests all data to be collected into one executor.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but sorry if the first comment was misleading but I stated 5-6k records/second so in a day the data might stretch to 1-2 million data.So if you could help me with the same.

Comment: are you understanding my point. your requirement suggests that it cannot be done in distributed mode. and accumulating such huge data on one node is not a good idea. and there is no other way than to collect the data in one node and generate the extra column for grouping and your requirement just needs that extra column

Comment: I am figuring my way in this so I might sound silly at some places but there must be some way to fetch the desired result on large data in a distributed mode,I am not much experienced in the same that is why looking for help.Any form of help or other way to approach the problem will be valuable for me.

Comment: yes there is a way as I did to generate some sort of information for grouping as I did but in distributed manner. :)

Comment: I have upvoted the answer already but it will cause lot of memory problem since as I already told you that 5-6k records/second so 1-2 million records per day.

Comment: thanks for the upvote. Yes the solution would certainly be slow as only one executor is working when generating that extra column. Can't you generate that extra column when you receive the data? if yes then you can remove the column generating code. if no then you would have to find a way to generate that extra column when you receive the data. Hope its helpful :)